# Self-signed applet doesn't get a full permission

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet, accesscontrolexception

I've googled lots of links like [oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.htmlhttp://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/index.html) and [velocity review](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t145778-p2-giving-applet-full-permission-without-policy-file.html) and stackoverlow too, but still no success.

The point is simple. Jar is signed using:

```
keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keystore compstore -keypass bca321 -dname "cn=test" -storepass abc123
jarsigner -keystore compstore -storepass abc123 -keypass bca321 -signedjar SignedJar.jar UnsignedJar.jar signFiles
```

And it runs perfectly on local machine. But when SignedJar.jar is used like an applet via HTTP(S), even if user accepts certificate (IE or FF or Chrome - no difference), it stops working with:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (javax.smartcardio.CardPermission Broadcom Corp Contacted SmartCard 0 connect)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.smartcardio.TerminalImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Yes, it tries to read from smartcard inserted in terminal, and gets an exception on calling connect.

Yes, I've tried this approach too:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
...
```

But with no luck. So where is the catch?

Thanks in advance,
Kirill

Comment: Maybe you need to create a policy file that includes the following permission grant (this is just my guess for its entry, you need to investigate further on how to grant a permission for CardPermission...): `grant {  permission javax.smartcardio.CardPermission "Broadcom Corp Contacted SmartCard 0", "connect"; }; ` See [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#know)

Comment: Have you signed all the code, including libraries? (With the same signature, and adding `Trusted-Only: true` to the manifest.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today, java 1.7.0_11, applet jars signed with self-signed certificate added to the list of trusted certificates. It went away when I *removed* the section in my policy file that granted my applet's codebase all permissions.

Answer (score 0):

After creating public/private keys, creating the associate certificate and signing which one of your applet jars with the certificate you should create a hash for each file in the JAR and sign them with the private key. These hashes, the public key, and the certificate must be added to the META-INF directory of the JAR file alongside the JAR’s manifest.

Here is the command line:

```
$ jar -tf SignedApplet.jar
```

See [link](http://www.jade-cheng.com/uh/ta/signed-applet-tutorial/)