# Java Applet Using aws sdk Getting Access Denied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, japplet

I am currently writing a Java applet (actually JApplet) that uses the Java AWS SDK to download a few files from my S3 bucket. The Applet works very well when I run it on the Applet Viewer in Eclipse, but I run into problems when I try running it on a browser.

I have indeed read a few SO questions on similar issues, but after following the answers provided, I still haven't found a solution to this problem.

At first I tried exporting a runnable jar with all dependencies included, at least for testing. But I got this error message in every browser that I tested in (Firefox, Chrome and IE):

```
access denied ("java.util.propertyPermission" "com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking" "read")
```

After some searching I found that this could be because my jar was not signed. So I self-signed it and tried again only to get the same error. I even decided to work with separate jars instead of packing them into a single jar and sign them all, to no avail.

The AwsCredentials.properties file is current and resides in the same directory as the jars, though I don't think that is what is causing the problem.

The code in HTML that I am using to embed the applet:

```
<applet code="path.to.class.Packer" 
        archive="signed-packer.jar" 
        width="400px" height="200px">       
</applet>
```

Let me know if you'd like more information.
I'd appreciate any help on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: *"..I self-signed it and tried again only to get the same error."*   Were you [prompted to accept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986333/appearance-of-java-security-dialog) the digitally signed code?

Comment: Yes, I was. I allowed it by pressing "run".

Comment: Does the applet get called by JS?  What is the code?  Is it available for us to visit (if so, where)?

Comment: No, there is no javascript in the page. It's is not up anywhere, because I need to solve this first. :/

Comment: *"It's is not up anywhere, because I need to solve this first."*  Sometimes an applet problem is not solved until others get to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.  An applet running in a browser sandbox is not allowed to read arbitrary Java system properties.  It is a security restriction.  Signing the applet JAR file *should be* sufficient, provided that Java accepts the signing certificate.  (Have you added your self-signed certificate to your Java installation's keystore?)

Related question: [Self-signed applet doesn't get a full permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882226/self-signed-applet-doesnt-get-a-full-permission)

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by adding the certificate to the keystore. I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/java-applet/662-how-sign-java-applet.html). 
A prompt comes up when the applet loads for me to give permission for it to run.

Comment: And do you give it permission?

Comment: I did. I pressed "run" on the dialog. Another one opened later asking if I wanted to block some components for 'security reasons' and I selected no.